# jQuery add and remove class for navigation

Tags: jquery, html

In the fiddle example below, I need to have an addClass and removeClass for active and non-active elements in the navigation (#menu li). I tried a few combination but it keeps adding the 'current' class to all the menu li's instead of the one that is clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/AyNSS/

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure If this is what you want, Try below and let me know..

```
    $('#menu li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/AyNSS/7/) here

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me unless I don't understand what you're trying to do.

```
$('#menu li a').click(function() {

        // remove active class
        $('#menu li a').removeClass('active');
        // add active class
        $(this).addClass('active');
        ...
 });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AyNSS/5/)